# Identificar cuándo se cierra un form en java desde otro form

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola alguien me puede explicar ¿como puedo verificar cuándo una ventana A fue cerrada por el método `dispose()` pero estando en la ventana B?

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, ha sido de mucha ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo esta técnica. Pero ten en cuenta que funciona entre ventana padre y ventana hija. Si la ventanas son hermanas, tendrás que hacer algo diferente.

1. Crea un método en la ventana principal para recibir las notificaciones
2. Crea una clase base para todas las ventanas hijas. (ej: ChildWindow)
3. Crea un constructor en ChildWindow que reciba la clase principal.
4. Atrapa el evento `windowClosed` en la clase ChildWindow y llama al método creado en el punto 1.

Aquí te dejo una maqueta de como funciona esta técnica.

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    // ...

    public void childClosed(String windowName, WindowEvent e) { 
         // aqui tienes la notificacion, con un identificador de cual ventana se cerro
         // y el evento que lo produjo.         
    }

}

public class ChildWindow extends JFrame {
    private MainWindow mainWindow;
    private String windowName;

    public ChildWindow(MainWindow mainWindow, String windowName) {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
        this.windowName = windowName;

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

                // Cuando la ventana se cierra, notifica a mainWindow
                mainWindow.childClosed(windowName, e);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Implementación de una ventana hija:

```
public class Opciones extends ChildWindow {
   // implementas 
}
```

Ejemplo de uso, dentro de `MainWindow`, por ejemplo en el manejador del menu Opciones.

```
// en MainWindow, cuando creas la ventana Opciones
Opciones opcionesFrame = new Opciones(this, "opciones");
```

Así, cuando se llama al método `dispose()` de la ventana hija, automáticamente se lanza el evento `windowClosed` lo que termina llamando a al método propietario `childClosed` y recibes la notificación.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho